# How do I make my right-side margin equal on all resolutions?

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, display

I have a short unordered list. I basically just want to shrink the right margin so the borders don't contain the entire page.

In my current resolution, I have the right margin set to 35em. This works when my window is minimized, but when I go back into fullscreen (1920x1080) the right margin is too large, almost reaching the other side of the webpage.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-right: 35em;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>eggs</li>
  <li>milk</li>
  <li>cheese</li>
  <li>bacon</li>
  <li>juice</li>
  <li>bagels</li>
</ol>
```

Low resolution (what I want it to always look like): http://prntscr.com/ml567o

And the high resolution (the issue): http://prntscr.com/ml56ip

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto`?

Comment: display: inline-block;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

35em with a default `font-size` (16px in Chrome) would be about 35 x 12 = 560px at least - use *pixels* instead. Also change `display` to `inline-block` so that the width of the `ol` is only as much as the content.

See demo below:

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding-right: 35px; /* CHANGED */
    padding-left: .5em;
    display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>eggs</li>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>bacon</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>bagels</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Changing the list display to an inline-block removed my need for margin completely. I just added a bit of padding to the left and right to adjust. Thanks so much; it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add inline-block property to the ol so the width and therefore the margin will take the space of its content. This way it will be equal on all resolutions.

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding: 0 .5em;
    display: inline-block; /* This is they key. The width, and therefore the margin will be based on its content */
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>eggs</li>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>bacon</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>bagels</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `width` for the `ol` element.

But to get the colored background *outside* the border like in your image, you need a container element...

Example without container:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
background: #ffd;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    margin-right: 5em;
    padding-left: .5em;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>eggs</li>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>bacon</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>bagels</li>
</ol>
```

WITH container element:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffd;
}

.container {
display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-right: 5em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>eggs</li>
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>bacon</li>
    <li>juice</li>
    <li>bagels</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assune the parent container within which your `ol` has a specified width so that you can give the `ol` a relative width (say... 50%)
Then you can use `{ margin: auto; }` to make it be at the center always. Always have the behaviour of block elements and inline elements in mind. #cheers